# How can I make a cell update with the current date, using a dropdown next to the cell?

Tags: date, google-apps-script, google-sheets, timestamp

I need to make Data Validation on a range of cells. I want a dropdown list, where the only option is the current date. To get the current date, I can use `=TODAY()`. The problem is, that the dates don't remain static. When the sheet recalculates, so will all the dates. I need the dates to remain the same.

How can I work around this?

I found [a blog](http://yogi--anand-consulting.blogspot.com/2012/01/yogisave-date-cell-was-changed.html) where the answer might be, but I can't see how the author has made his spreadsheet.

Comment: Why would you need to have dropdown list with a single value? Why can't you put TODAY() in the entry form, and copy the *value* to the sheet?

Comment: Because some people will be using the spreadsheet, and they dont like to copy/paste all the time. So i want to make a select item for them, that puts the current date in the cell, without the date recalculating

Comment: Would it be accurate to rephrase your question as "How can I make a Google spreadsheet update a cell with the current date, but only in response to a user's action?"  In other words, does it _have_ to be a drop-down, or could it be a button labeled "Update Date"?

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I will rephrase my question. The drop-down is the preferred choice, because the user doesnt have to move the mouse very much. There are several columns that the user can update this way in a row, therefor it is more efficient if the user does not to move the mouse a whole lot

Comment: Take a look at Google AppScript, specifically the onOpen() function, which will execute a script when you open the spreadsheet.  Getting warmer?  :-)

Comment: Your hint led me to a solution that i have posted as answer. Thanks :)

Comment: Kenci- You should get @AdamLiss to post an answer you can award the bounty to since his was the useful help (and you can't give yourself the bounty anyways).

Comment: @blahdiblah - My schedule this morning didn't leave me enough time to write a complete answer, and Kenci did the hard part anyway, so I'm happy to forgo the bounty.  Thanks for the PR, though!  Much appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I will have a dropdown item which says "dags dato". Next i use an eventlistener that checks if the text in a cell is changed to "dags dato".

if so, it puts the current date in the cell, like this:

```
function onEdit(event)
{
  var ss = event.source.getActiveSheet();
  var r = event.source.getActiveRange();

  var currentValue = r.getValue();

  if(currentValue == "dags dato")
  {
    var dd = Utilities.formatDate(new Date(), "GMT", "yyyy-MM-dd");
    r.setValue(dd);
  }
}
```